# robotium testing wait time between each clicks

Tags: android, robotium

in robotium testing, is it possible to set a wait time between clicks? For example, I have 2 buttons(A & B). I want robotium to click on button A and then 20 seconds later click on button B.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

u can use this code its working fine

solo.clickOnButton(0);

solo.sleep(20000); // 20 seconds

solo.clickOnButton(0);

Answer (score 3):

If the purpose is to wait for a fixed amount of time then use solo.sleep(20000). If you want to wait for a condition before moving on you can use the waitFor methods.